# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, glass-mapper, tds

I am using Glass.Mapper.sc ...

@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView

in sitecore Layout... Not Controller/View Rendering

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Any more details on the error you are seeing. Seems like you have only posted have a message without a full definition of your `@inherits` declaration either

Answer (score 1):

More information will be helpful but i have seen this exception when the glass mapper config files (Glass.Mapper.Sc.config and Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config) are missing in the App_Config/Include directory

Comment: I wasn't paying attention, and the facepalm this comment caused finally helped me see the light.  Thank you.